# Wordpress: Issues with shared SSL and custom permalinks

Tags: wordpress

I want to apply SSL to about 4 pages of my wordpress site which visitors will only see when they go through a checkout procedure.

I am using the wordpress plugin 'WordPress HTTPS (SSL)' for the SSL capabilities - [WordPress HTTPS (SSL)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/)

I have a shared SSL certificate and the SSL pages only display when I set the permalinks to be default. Otherwise I get a 404 error. This seems to be quite a common error.

I really want the site to display Pretty Permalinks for all pages and posts on the site, but I am willing to compromise on these 4 pages.

Therefore, my question is, can I set all pages to be Pretty Permalinks except these 4 SSL pages, which need to be set as default pages? If so, how?

I have tried several Permalink plugins without any real success.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your server is allowing the use of Pretty Permalinks?

1. Do you have the mod_rewrite Apache module enabled?
2. Are you allowed to override server configuration with `.htaccess` files? This is specified by the `AllowOverride` Apache directive(found in the Apache configuration file)

If you have no idea about those - ask your hosting provider for support - they should know if those are enabled.

The easiest way to confirm that the Permalinks are working in general is to disable the WordPress HTTPS (SSL) plugin and see if the pretty permalinks are working or you are still getting the 404 page.

Comment: Hi Nikola - thanks for the reply. Pretty Permalinks do work - but do not work over shared SSL. This seems to be a common problem. Default permalinks do work using shared SSL.

Comment: I haven't encountered that behavior before(I haven't coded a lot on SSL protected sites). I'm sorry but I won't be able to help you then. Hope you find out what the problem is - if you do and nobody answered, feel free to post it as an answer and accept it.